# Login form inaccessable?

Tags: users

When I go to mysite.com/user I see the login form. But it is not accessable. I cannot click in either of the text boxes and the button does not click.

This is true in Firefox, Chrome, and recent IE. It does work in IE8 for some reason.

Anyone have a clue why this should be? I tried moving it to other regions. I looked at the HTML and it appears to be fine. Maybe I'm missing some crucial Javascript?

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: This is almost certainly a css issue and probably something we can't help with here. Make sure that you don't have any floated 100% width divs with a higher z-index than the login box overlapping it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like there is some invisible HTML over the top of your form.

Inspect one of the form elements with Firebug and see what it actually selects, then fix the HTML / CSS.

Comment: This was the issue. Thanks also to Clive and Alexei for helping out.

Answer (score 0):

With firebug or chrome dev tools, right click on the form, and 'Expect element'. Then you will see what element gets on top over it and blocks it. Often it's an ill-terminated div, or a bad float. Or your form is floated and some clearfix is missing.